# Asymptotic number of lattice points in an annulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-geometry, integer-lattices

Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $K(n) = |\lbrace \gamma \in \Gamma: |\gamma| < n\rbrace|$.

> How do I show $K(n) - K(n-1)$ is $O(n)$?

By the theory of integration I know that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{K(n)}{\pi n^2} = 1$.
But this gives nothing related to what I want.
Please help me proceed.

Comment: $K(n)-K(n-1) \le 4 \pi (n^2-(n-1)^2) = O(n)$

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain how you got the estimates? I don't see why the coefficients of $n^2$ and $(n-1)^2$ are the same ($4\pi$).

Comment: hmm, I was wrong. It’s not as simple.

Comment: But the idea should work. Consider the area between two circles and upper bound how many squares can be covered. Each square give you at most 4 points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sketch.

A circle of radius $n-3$ has area $\pi(n-3)^2$. So at least this many unit square touches it. Each square touches it must be entirely within the circle of radius $n-1$. This give a lower bound.

Similarly a circle of radius $n$ contains at most $\pi (n+2)^2$ squares.

So difference is at most $O(n)$ squares.

Comment: Clever, thanks!